# "Greater than" and "less than" operator not working in a query

Tags: php, mysqli

"Equal" and "Not equal" operator works great in my searching query.
However, "Greater than" and "less than" operator is not working.

For instance, when I type "SELECT * FROM `expressForm` WHERE `efPostage` != 460", I can get
https://i.stack.imgur.com/5a9rs.png, which works great.

However, when I type "SELECT * FROM `expressForm` WHERE `efPostage` <= 460", I get "No result". It is strange because there are some efPostage values smaller than 460.

#### PHP code

```
$mysqli = mysqli_connect("localhost",  "XXX",  "XXX", "express")
  or die("Error connecting to database: ".mysqli_error($mysqli));

$sql = trim(preg_replace('/\s\s+/', ' ', $sQuery));
$sql = htmlspecialchars($sql);
$sql = mysqli_real_escape_string($mysqli, $sql);
$sql = stripslashes($sql);

$sQueryResults = $mysqli->query($sql);

if(mysqli_num_rows($sQueryResults) > 0) {
     if (strpos($sql, 'FROM `expressForm`') !== false) {
        echo "<h3 class = \"entity\"> expressForm </h3>";
        echo '<table class=\"table table-striped table-bordered table-hover\">';
        echo "<tr><th>efSerialNo</th><th>signedStID</th><th>efOfficeCode</th><th>efDateMailed</th><th>efPostage</th></tr>";
        while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($sQueryResults)) {
            echo "B";
            echo "<tr><td>";
            echo $row['efSerialNo'];
            echo "</td><td>";
            echo $row['signedStID'];
            echo "</td><td>";
            echo $row['efOfficeCode'];
            echo "</td><td>";
            echo $row['efDateMailed'];
            echo "</td><td>";
            echo $row['efPostage'];                                
            echo "</td></tr>";
        }
        echo "</table>";
    }
else {
    echo "No results<br>";
}

$mysqli->close();
```

Comment: `$sql = trim(preg_replace('/\s\s+/', ' ', $sQuery)); $sql = htmlspecialchars($sql); $sql = mysqli_real_escape_string($mysqli, $sql); $sql = stripslashes($sql);` — Are you just throwing random escaping functions about and praying that you'll protect yourself without breaking the data?!

Comment: Your attempts to escape user input seem to be pretty much all over the place, it looks a lot like shotgun debugging to me.  https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shotgun_debugging  Normally you'd use prepared statements to address these issues for you.  Both PDO and mysqli support prepared statements

Comment: *"“Greater than” and “less than” operator not working in a query"* ... what do you expect when you wrap the SQL in `htmlspecialchars`... you're converting `>` and `<` to **HTML** entities for an **SQL** query.

Comment: You only need to escape the variable you are comparing in the SQL statment not the entire request

Comment: By the way, stripslashes was removed from PHP on the grounds that it was ultimately worse than useless and actually an active menace.  If you're using a version of PHP that still has stripslashes then I suspect you might need to update

Answer (score 1):

You're breaking your query by applying things like htmlspecialchars() to the entire thing!  This will result in things like `<=` being turned into `&lt;=`

You should only worry about escaping the variables you're using in the query, not the query as a whole.

```
$query = "SELECT * FROM table WHERE column = '" 
         . mysqli_real_escape_string ($mysqli, $parameter)
         . "'";
```

Better yet, you should be using [prepared statements](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.prepare.php) for dealing with parameters in queries.  This will cause the database engine to handle your escaping for you, with the added benefit that it makes SQL injection attacks far more difficult.

```
$stmt = $mysqli->prepare ("SELECT * FROM table WHERE column = ?");
$stmt->bind_param ("i", $value); // "i" indicates that this is expected to be an integer.  See documentation for binding other types
$stmt->execute();
$stmt->bind_result($result);
$stmt->fetch();
var_dump ($result);
```

It's a bit of a faff to set up but the benefits are more than worth it.

Comment: If I need to type a query like "SELECT * FROM expressForm WHERE efPostage != 460" initially, how can I just escape the variable in the query?